# Is available standalone ffmpeg as application

Tags: android, ffmpeg

Is available this application?
I do not want compile ffmpeg and add it to android project.
I want execute application over sh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Build in kubuntu:

```
--target-os=linux --cross-prefix=arm-linux-androideabi- --arch=arm --sysroot=~/app/android-ndk-r8b/platforms/android-3/arch-arm --disable-doc --disable-htmlpages --disable-txtpages --disable-podpages --disable-ffplay --disable-ffprobe --disable-ffserver --disable-network --disable-debug --enable-libamr-wb --prefix=../build/ffmpeg/armeabi --extra-cflags= --extra-ldflags=
```